Issue with Google API restrictions in Expo React Native app
I'm building an Expo React Native app that uses the Google Books API. I'm unable to restrict its usage to my app. I've tried everything and followed the documentation to the letter. I've even asked ChatGPT for help.
I'm currently using the credentials (SHA-1) provided by Google Play but I can't make any calls. I've also tested my credentials in the development app and the same thing happens, I can't make API calls.
I'm using fetch to make API calls, not sure if that's the issue.
const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${query}&key=${process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_BOOKS_API}`;

const response = await fetch(url);

This is what I'm using:
On Google Play console:

On Google Cloud Console:

On app.json:

I've tried getting the credentials for both keys, following the documentation, etc.
